# How to determine a match between 2 JSONs?

Tags: java, json, string-math

I have two data sources, and both of them return JSONs.

I want to ensure that there is some percentage of match (overlap of data, if you will) in the two JSONs, so as to collate them and store in a single record.

Is comparing the entropy of the two strings the best way? Are there any other solutions? I use Java, and could also use scala for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert them to xml and then use [xdiff](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/niagara/papers/xdiff) algorithm, or put every json record to a single line, and use unix `diff`. Or convert it to an internal tree representation, and apply [parallel tree difference](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.8675) algorithm. That depends on what kind of difference are you looking for and doesn't depend on the implementation language.